# Programatically select address on checkout - Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

How to programatically select customer address on checkout, so the customer can immediatelly click on Place order button without updating address?

If customer has default billing and shipping adresses set then those default values are immediately selected on checkout, otherwise customer needs to select and update address before placing order. I want to do that programatically (select first available address in dropdown if exists)